# Use top div and bottom div backgrounds to create a gradient that connects them in middle div

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, gradient

I have three divs. The top one has a background image set as center/cover. The bottom one is all white. I would like to apply a gradient background to the middle div that continues the image from the top and transitions into the white of the bottom one. The image in question has different nuances of grey at the bottom, so without this it creates a clear delimitation between the top and middle div which I would like to remove. Is there a way to do this using JS or CSS?

HTML Code is as follows:

```
<div class="topdiv">
TITLE
</div>
<div class="middlediv">
REVIEWS
</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">
REST OF PAGE
</div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
.topdiv {
        height:100%!important;
background:url('some image that has different nuances of grey at the bottom.png') scroll no-repeat center/cover!important;
}

.middlediv {
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(continue topdiv image to white);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(continue topdiv image to white);
background: linear-gradient(continue topdiv image to white);
    height:250px;
}

.bottomdiv {
background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gradient over the image can approximate this:

```css
.top,
.bottom{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
}
.top {
  background:
    linear-gradient(#0000 70%,#fff),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200) center/ cover;
}
.bottom {
  background:#fff;
}


body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Or mask and some overlap

```css
.top,
.bottom{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
}
.top {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200) center/ cover;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(0deg,#0000 ,#000 50px);
}
.bottom {
  background:#fff;
  margin-top:-50px; /* same as the value inside mask */
}


body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```